# Angular 2 - (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?, ?).(…)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs, ng2-charts

I'm attempting to build an application and I'm hitting snag after snag, and just when I think I break through I don't. Now, an application which once accepted AppComponent, once I introduced ng2-charts.js, now does not. I receive this error:

[image]

I'm using System.js and Node.js to run this application. I've uninstalled and reinstalled my node modules folder. Here are my `app.module.ts` and my app.component.ts files:

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import TwitterService from "./twitter.service";
import BarGraphComponent from "./bar-graph.component";
import LineGraphComponent from "./line-graph.component";
import { ChartsModule } from "ng2-charts";
import {DataService} from "./data.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, ChartsModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, BarGraphComponent, LineGraphComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [TwitterService, DataService]
})
export default class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
import {DataService} from "./data.service";
import TwitterService from "./twitter.service";
import {IoToken} from "./di";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "/app/app.component.html",
    providers: [TwitterService, DataService, {provide: IoToken, useValue: io}]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private twitter: TwitterService, private data: DataService) {}

    topWords = this.data.topWords;
    topWordsCount = this.data.topWordsCount;
    topHashtags = this.data.topHashtags;
    topHashtagsCount = this.data.topHashtagsCount;
    tweets = this.data.tweets;
    tweetsOverTime = this.data.tweetsOverTime;

    getTweetCount = () => this.data.totalCount;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.data.setSource(this.twitter.startStreaming());
    }
}
```

It should be noted that socket.io is used in and declared in child components, but I commented out the code in the child components to ensure this wasn't the issue. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you provide the services at `@NgModule()` **and** `@Component()`?

Comment: Did you add `@Injectable()` to your service classes?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - it's what the guy did in the video tutorial I was following, and I did inject `@Injectable` in the two services.

Comment: I hope you didn't inject `@Injectable()` you should only prefix the service classes with `@Injectable()` Can you please also add the code of the services? (at least the class declaration and constructor, other methods can be left off).

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote - yes, I prefixed the services with `@Injectable()`